# How to retrieve the columns based on the UUID

Tags: mysql

In my application database the table is called Customer which has fields:

**CUSTOMER TABLE**

- cust_id
- cust_name
- cust_age

In above table `cust_id` data type is binary and UUID has been inserted into the table :
Insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ('444d264e-9024-11e4-968c-b82a72ad8ef8','swify',41);
```

The data has been inserted successfully . Similarly in this fashion i have inserted multiple records into the DB

Now i want to retrieve a particular record from the DB Usin select statement.

I tried this approach but it's giving no rows

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE cust_id='444d264e-9024-11e4-968c-b82a72ad8ef8';
```

Hence, My question is how can i retrieve a record based on the UUID values;

Comment: Can you share the ddl you used to create the table please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE cust_id LIKE '444d264e-9024-11e4-968c-b82a72ad8ef8';
```

Comment: It's still giving 0 rows returned

Comment: can you tell me the datatype of cust_id field?

Comment: data type of cust_id is binary(16) and I first typed select UUID() and inserted the returned value into the cust_id field

Comment: This structure has been created by some one else ... so i too personally dont have much idea...

Comment: when you select UUID(), that time do you think proper value is going to be inserted in table?

Comment: Yes i think... and in the mysql workbench its giving BLOB in the Field

Comment: exact value is going to be stored in table?